# customizing scopes/lenses?

Tags: unity, lenses, scopes

In the video scopes it shows 2 of my movies in my ~/Videos/Movies(/Media/Videos/Movies) folder. When I have some 20 movies in there. The scope wont show my TV shows either under ~/Videos/TV_Shows/. I want it to show up with as in the scopes where it says "My Videos" as "Movies" and a second one under that as "TV Shows" Setup as seasons where you click on a season and it shows all the episodes.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the results by writing new scopes, but that is probably not the answer you're looking for ([here's a tutorial for doing so using the Ubuntu 13.10 API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/scopes/writing-a-unity-scope/)).

The default videos scope does not provide any hooks to alter its results in the way you've described.  If the existing scope is ignoring some of your videos under `~/Videos` though, that sounds like a bug (and should probably be reported as such).  Is there anything unusual about your system?